# Linux Kernel version confusion

Tags: kernel, versions

I want to upgrade my `Linux Kernel` to `6.0.6` as mentioned [on this site](https://www.kernel.org/) that this is the most stable release right now. I am downloading `Kernel` [from this site](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/).

**Kernel Version** on this site are like this.
[Site Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbhZN.png)

```
v6.0-rc1/   2022-08-15 01:03    -    
v6.0-rc2/   2022-08-22 02:11    -    
v6.0-rc3/   2022-08-29 00:22    -    
v6.0-rc4/   2022-09-22 19:50    -    
v6.0-rc5/   2022-09-23 05:32    -    
v6.0-rc6/   2022-09-22 19:21    -    
v6.0-rc7/   2022-09-26 01:14    -    
v6.0.1/     2022-10-12 13:22    -    
v6.0.2/     2022-10-15 11:12    -    
v6.0.3/     2022-10-21 16:13    -    
v6.0.4/     2022-10-26 13:59    -    
v6.0.5/     2022-10-26 12:39    -    
v6.0/       2022-10-02 23:26    -    
v6.1-rc1/   2022-10-17 04:22    -    
v6.1-rc2/   2022-10-24 04:13    -
```

There is no `Kernel Version` named `v6.0.6`. I think it is `6.0` as it after `6.0.5` but I am not sure. Please help me to download the stable `Linux Kernel`.

**REASON TO UPGRADE KERNEL**

My laptop is new and a few devices `Laptop Camera` and `Keyboard` do not work properly on `Kernel 5.15`. I installed `Kernel 6.0` and it is working perfectly. But I am not sure if it is a stable version or not.

**KERNEL I AM USING**

```
Linux 6.0.0-060000-generic
```

Comment: Do you have a link you can give me so I can see this is the most stable release for Ubuntu?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details.   FYI:  The *latest* release is *almost never* the most *stable*, it's just the latest to be classed as *stable* (often the most *unstable* of the *stable* kernels).

Comment: Yes, I know it is not the most stable kernel but my devices work perfectly on the latest kernel that matters to me. I have not experienced any issues yet in `v6`.

Comment: Please add OS & release details to your question.

Comment: I am using `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`

Comment: Please add that release detail to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel `6.0.6` has been added to the PPA.

[image]

In the future, I think you need to allow at least 24 hours to pass before jumping to conclusions.